# Inserting data into a nested json using node js with different ejs forms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, mongoose-schema

I am using ejs with html to connect to my node js server. Basically I have two files, one with a calendar to select **dates** and another that allows to **search rooms and select time slots.**
Now I have a schema, there my json attribute is -->

bookedSlots: [{

```
date: {

  type: [Date],

  required: true

},

times: {

  type: [String],

  required: true

}
```

}]

How do i fix this? i want to process both the data in a single endpoint although I am using "forms" to send the data to backend. (Using req.body)

Can someone please help?

I am not able to receive both data at once as files are different and two forms are there. It worked fine when the schema did not have nested json attribute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.